# A biography movie about a first nude photo model in the history

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a biography movie about the story of first nude photo model in the usa and also in the world. The time in the movie is probably 20's and 30's . It wasn't the war years and it was a career movie so at least 10-15 years have passed from the beginning of the movie to the end. I couldn't remember which year it was made in but it was before 2003, and usa made movie.

A young, unexperienced, naive girl from a small town goes to a big city (la or ny) to be a celebrity. She goes to the modeling agencies and photo agencies for this dream. She was white, with black hair and eyebrows, tall about 5'7'' or 1.70 m, between 18-23, had a curvy body like the stars at that time. She met one of the big boss's in the town and he told her to do something very different in order to shine and offered being a nude model. She surprised about this offer but accepted it.

She was taken some nude photos and the boss wanted to advertise this. He spread the news to the journalists. Everybody was shocked when they heard of it.  He contacted some of them and arranged a media day for her. Bunch of journalists and photographers had come. They took lots of photos and asked many questions about her age, hometown, education, family, dreams, career goals, etc. One of the photographers asked her to turn around and she did it. She had an underwear but it didn't cover much of her body. They laughed, took pictures and expressed their greeting to meet her butt. They made articles about her in their newspapers and magazines. She become popular in a very short time.

I remember a scene that between her and a photographer. He had some feelings but he never expressed it to her. He was white, blonde, in his 30's and medium sized. They were in the woods nearby a tree alone. I think it was fall because there were lots of leaves in the ground. He started to take topless photos of her. Suddenly he asked her to as if she can remove the underwear and she accepted it. He took bunch of photos in a close range. After that he told her, if he shoot too many nude photos, his boss would question him. Plus he said that he couldn't publish all of them. She confirmed that and put back her underwear.

Eventually she became a celebrity and had a long career. It could be a movie of a real story or a story of someone's, under the fake name and some revisions.

Comment: [**Audrey Munson**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audrey_Munson), perhaps?

Comment: @Paulie_D I checked her but she's not the one i'm looking for. I couldn't remember the year of the movie and whether it was black&white or in color but the picture quality was good and i'm sure it was older than at least 1970. And the girl looked like Gina Lollobrigida especially in this photo. She had similar mouth and nose shape but had a more curvy body and ronde face. https://www.flickr.com/photos/hi-hodaddario/6243598030

Comment: So are you sure it's about the *first* nude model in the USA/World? This seems unlikely...more like about a specific known person.

Comment: @Paulie_D  She wasn't a nude-art or fashion (runway) model. She was a photo model, shooting photos for magazines, posters, covers etc. As i've said before, it could be a movie of a real person but under a fake name and revised story of her, but i'm sure she was the first person on her profession.

Comment: @Michael You said you couldn't remember if the movie was black&white or color. "The Notorious Bettie Page" was black & white during the first half, and color in the second half!

Comment: @BrettFromLA No wonder i was confused :) By the way i thought the time in the movie was much earlier like 20's or 30's but it was 50's ...

Comment: @Michael American movies were mostly black & white in the 1930's & 40's, and most American movies were in color in the 50's. They did the same thing in "The Notorious Bettie Page", if I recall correctly:  The parts that were supposed to take place in the 30's & 40's were shot in black and white, and the parts that took place in the 50's were shot in color. (I also think it changed to color when Bettie arrived in California, but it's been a long time since I saw the movie.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The Notorious Bettie Page** - sounds like this to me - it's from 2005, she has black hair.  It is a true story.  It stars Gretchen Mol.  If you'd mentioned that she became a missionary in the end that would've clinched it.

Comment: Yes, exactly it is. What a suprise ending, i couldn't remember that.